# Getting frame of a view in a sub-subview

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

So, let me try to explain what happens. So, I have this view structure:

```
ViewController
HeaderView -> Subview of ViewController
MenuView -> Subview of HeaderView
```

I'm using auto layout inside each view.

My problem it's that in MenuView when I tried to use frame size to anchor some views, the frame it's still 0.0 and therefore, it does not layout anything, I think it's maybe because it has still not got it from ViewController, because when I layout MenuView inside HeaderView, I also use the frame size.

Any help?

Edit:
By the way, also bounds are 0.0

Code:

**HeaderController**

```
lazy var headerView: HeaderView = {
       let hv = HeaderView(maxHeight: self.maxHeight, medHeight: self.medHeight, minHeight: self.minHeight, paddingBetween: 10)
        return hv
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupViews()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        headerView.headerControllerDelegate = self
    }

    func setupViews() {
        addSubview(collectionView)
        addSubview(lineView)
        bringSubview(toFront: lineView)

        _ = collectionView.anchor(top: topAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, right: rightAnchor, left: leftAnchor)

        lineViewLeftAnchor = lineView.anchor(top: nil, bottom: bottomAnchor, right: nil, left: leftAnchor, topConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, leftConstant: 0, widthConstant: frame.size.width / 4, heightConstant: 1.5)[1]


    }
}
```

**HeaderView**

```
 let menuView: MenuView = {
        let mv = MenuView()
        return mv
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = Theme.PRIMARY_DARK_COLOR
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    convenience init(maxHeight: CGFloat, medHeight: CGFloat, minHeight: CGFloat, paddingBetween containerPadding: CGFloat) {
        self.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
        self.maxHeight = maxHeight
        self.medHeight = medHeight
        self.minHeight = minHeight
        self.containerPadding = containerPadding

        collapseBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleCollapse), for: .touchUpInside)
        setupViews()
    }

    func setupViews() {
        addSubview(menuView)
        _ = menuView.anchor(top: menuContainer.topAnchor, bottom: menuContainer.bottomAnchor, right: menuContainer.rightAnchor, left: menuContainer.leftAnchor)
    }
```

**MenuView**

```
extension MenuView: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as? MenuCell {
            cell.menuLabel.text = menuItems[indexPath.row]
            cell.menuLabel.textColor = fontColor
            return cell
        }
        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return menuItems.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: frame.size.width / 4, height: frame.size.height)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }
```

This is not the whole code but I think it's the important part.

Comment: Please post your codes or screenshot of your interface builder. Do you layout your views programmatically?

Comment: @Glenn I layout programmatically, I updated the post with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most obvious solution is to get the frame of `HeaderView` in the `MenuView`'s `layoutSubviews` func.

But why are you going to get the size of `HeaderView`? In Auto Layout you arrange your app's UI using relations between UI elements, so you shouldn't care about the concrete value of the frame.

---

**Updated:**

The proper solution is invalidating your layout when the bounds of the collection view changes.

You have to override `shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange:)` and return `true`.

> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout/1617781-shouldinvalidatelayoutforboundsc

And call the `collectionView`'s `invalidateLayout` in the `layoutSubviews` of `MenuView`.

Comment: I want the size because I have 4 cells and I want their size to be 1/4 of the screen with.

Comment: @LeonardoEmilioDominguez I uploaded a sample project, hope this have helped you. https://www.dropbox.com/s/ifuhf4dptt580dx/TestCollectionView.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

The question needs a little more context but are you trying to grab the frame size in code or are you stating that the views aren't getting laid out as per their constraints.

If it is in code you need to be aware that `frame.size` isn't available until `viewDidAppear` has been called.

Comment: I updated the post with the code. I thought about using viewDidAppear but the thing is, I'm subclassing from UIView and viewDidAppear it's a viewController method.